# error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: windows, msbuild, windows-10, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a target in my .csproj file which Looks like this:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetPackageVersion" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
<ParameterGroup>
  <FileName ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  <PackageVersion ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
</ParameterGroup>
<Task>
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
  <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
  <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
  var doc = XDocument.Load(FileName);
  var defaultNamespace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
  PackageVersion = doc.Root.Element(defaultNamespace.GetName("Identity")).Attribute("Version").Value;
]]>
</Code>
</Task>
</UsingTask>
<Target Name="GetZip">
<GetPackageVersion Filename="Package.appxmanifest">
  <Output PropertyName="PackageVersion" TaskParameter="PackageVersion" />
</GetPackageVersion>
<ItemGroup>
  <BinDirectoryFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\AppPackages\MyApp_$(PackageVersion)_x86_MyApp_Test\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Zip Files="@(BinDirectoryFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\AppPackages\MyApp_$(PackageVersion)_x86_MyApp_Test" ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Zip\MyApp_$(PackageVersion).zip" />
</Target>
```

My project is on GitLab and builds automatically when I commit something.
The project builds without any problems and than it should zip the apppackages. At the beginning it worked, but after installing the newest Windows 10 Version (1803) on my virtual machine it fails at the Zip target with this error:

> C:\Multi-Runner\builds\9fca3796\0\mobile\mail-windows\MyApp\MyApp.csproj(657,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". A required privilege is not held by the Client

I don't know why it comes up now. I don't changed anything. I have to say that if I call the target from a command prompt on my VM than it works.

Comment: Run as an administrator to resolve the error _"A required privilege is not held by the Client"_. See my answer for [NetBeans cannot connect to repository at gitlab repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687547/netbeans-cannot-connect-to-repository-at-gitlab-repository/50691830#50691830). That answer relates to running a Java application when accessing GitLab but the solution/workaround should be the same for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Windows 10 the default build location `C:\gitlab-runner\builds` is protected. One solution is to move the builds directory into the runner user's home folder by adding a `builds_dir` line to the runners section of your `config.toml` file. The escaped backslashes were required to parse the path in the .toml correctly.

```
builds_dir = "c:\\\Users\\\gitlab-ci-users\\\builds"
```

I had to restart my gitlab service in order for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit something similar, but not on my machine (at another team). Switching from CodeTaskFactory into RoslyCodeTaskFactory fixed it for us (but it won't build with MSBuild < 15.8)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2019