# NetBeans cannot connect to repository at (gitlab repository)

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Yesterday I installed a new version of Netbeans (NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)) and since then I can't connect to my gitlab repo (fails on trying to clone project). Credentials are fine, work on other computers and systems and I logged in over the browser(my first thought was that I tried a wrong password and banned my IP).

I use Windows 10, Java 1.8.0_31.

**EDIT:** Access to gitlab worked on an older version of NetBeans (not sure which one was it but above 8.0)

Updated JDK to 1.8.0_171 - still no success.

Also this was found in IDE log

> INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git]: java.lang.InternalError: Should not get here
>   java.lang.InternalError: Should not get here
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:901)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:578)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtil.createSymLink(FileUtil.java:96)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32_Java7.detectSymlinkSupport(FS_Win32_Java7.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32_Java7.supportsSymlinks(FS_Win32_Java7.java:71)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.create(FileRepository.java:306)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.create(Repository.java:169)
>       at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.InitRepositoryCommand.run(InitRepositoryCommand.java:89)
>       at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:80)
>       at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:77)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand.execute(GitCommand.java:77)
>       at org.netbeans.libs.git.GitClient.init(GitClient.java:871)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$33.call(GitClient.java:574)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$33.call(GitClient.java:570)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1$1.call(GitClient.java:956)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1.call(GitClient.java:979)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.FilesystemInterceptor.runWithoutExternalEvents(FilesystemInterceptor.java:496)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.Git.runWithoutExternalEvents(Git.java:282)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethodIntern(GitClient.java:989)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:916)
>   Caused: org.netbeans.libs.git.GitException
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:932)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:898)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.access$400(GitClient.java:892)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient.init(GitClient.java:570)
>   [catch] at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.clone.RepositoryStep$RepositoryStepProgressSupport.perform(RepositoryStep.java:323)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.performIntern(GitProgressSupport.java:115)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.run(GitProgressSupport.java:108)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
>       at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)

Comment: There are a lot of stuff that can fail. Try looking at NetBeans logs and so on for error messages.

Comment: [1] Nobody can resolve this issue based on the information you have posted. At a minimum please update your post with the actual details of the failure. [2] Was access to GitLab working for you with an earlier version of NetBeans? [3] You are using a very old version of JDK.  Consider using a more recent version. [4] Check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for any errors associated with your problem, and update your post if appropriate.

Comment: I've updated question.

Comment: Are you running NetBeans using a Windows compatibility mode? Creating symlinks should work fine in Win10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the code failed when trying to create a symbolic link by calling **Files.createSymbolicLink()**. To do that on Windows 10 you must run with Administrator rights, or you need to have the right to create a symbolic link, so the true solution to your problem is to set appropriate [User Account Control (UAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-overview). This is the case even if you created the file or directory to which you want to add a symbolic link.

If you open a **Command Prompt** window, create a directory and then try to add a symbolic link it will fail with the error *"You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation"*, but if you do the same thing when selecting **Run as Administrator** before opening a **Command Prompt** window it works fine:

[image: NoAdminRights]
[image: WithAdminRights]

The same principles apply when creating a symbolic link in a Java application on Windows 10, and again the proper solution is to set UAC appropriately. However, there is an easy workaround solution: just as you can open a **Command Prompt** window as an administrator, you can also run NetBeans as an administrator:

[image: RunAsAdmin]

Once you do that the **java.lang.InternalError** should be gone.

You can run the trivial Java application below to confirm that admin rights are needed when creating a symbolic link under Windows 10. The application fails with a **FileSystemException** (*"A required privilege is not held by the client."*) when calling **Files.createSymbolicLink()** from NetBeans if it is started normally, but works fine when NetBeans is **Run as administrator**.

```
public class SymLink {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String originName = "c:\\ThisIsJunk";
        String targetName = originName + "SymLnk";
        Path origin = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(originName));
        Path target = Paths.get(targetName);
        try {
            Files.delete(target);
        } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
        }
        try {
            Path symLink = Files.createSymbolicLink(target, origin);
            System.out.println("Symbolic link created: " + symLink.toString());
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue mentioned above while running in Administrator Mode, I noticed I had Netbeans running in Windows 8 Compatibility mode. Unchecking compatibility mode, I was then able to connect to the Github repository.